# How to use C to write the result of added up integers into a csv file?

Tags: c, variables, csv, printf

My C code opens up a csv file with 5 numbers (1,2,3,4,5), adds them together and then returns the result to Python. I already understand how to do this, but now I'm trying to also make C write the result into the csv file.

I know that I have to use `f=fopen` with `"w"` instead of `"r"`,and then use `fprintf`.

I definitely have a problem with this part of the C code because when I do:

```
gcc file.c
```

in the linux command line it fails.

The part of the C code in the question looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
    printf("hello world\n");

    FILE *f;
    int a,b,c,d,e;

    f = fopen("goo.csv", "r");
    fscanf( f, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e);

    f = fopen("goo.csv", "w");
    fprintf(f, "%d+%d+%d+%d+%d", &a+&b+&c+&d+&e);

    return a+b+c+d+e;
}
```

I know that somewhere after the f=fopen part I've got something wrong...

```
f = fopen("goo.csv", "w");
fprintf(f, "%d+%d+%d+%d+%d", &a+&b+&c+&d+&e);
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You have other problems besides that it's not writing. Because when you fix that problem you have a much more serious problem, and that is that your [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) call is all wrong. First of all you add the *addresses* of the variables, then the [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) call expects *5* integers, but you will only provide one.

Comment: Everything in the `fprintf` line will be added together, and thus form one single value.

Comment: It's a bad idea to open a file that you did not close before.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that I make these stupid errors. This is not me being evil, I'm just fairly new to programming.

Comment: All errors are stupid, once you solve them :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code after `return a+b+c+d+e;` will not be executed.

If you really want to write the result to the same file, you should close it, before (re)writing.

Comment: Just noticed that thanks... however there still seems to be a problem which I've created.

Comment: The first part of your answer is irrelevent now...Since OP edited his code!

Comment: @CoolGuy - Tx. Is it my responsibility to follow this up and ammend the answer. I am new to stack overflow?

Comment: Jakub, you don't have to do so - follow-up *or* change your answer, or even delete it. It's not your "responsibility" in *any* possible way to keep up if the OP changes the question. In fact, if the OP does so too liberally, he will probably attract the attention of one of the SO moderators.

Comment: Ktx. Just don´t like to leave mess/nonsense arround.

Comment: You _can_ open a file read/write and lseek back to the beginning without closing it.  Databases would be hard to manage without that.

Comment: @technosaurus - of course. Yet Alex is probably better off just closing the file. Guess it is not the right time to teach him how shorten a r-w file...